# D3.js line plot pandas dataframe JSON

Tags: javascript, python, json, d3.js

Can anyone provide a good example of how to use D3 to parse the standard output of a python pandas dataframe to_json() which ends up looking something like this:

```
"{"column1":{"2017-09-20T11:14:18.000Z":2.1,"2017-09-20T11:14:19.000Z":2.3,"2017-09-20T11:14:20.000Z":2.4}}"
```

Ultimately I am looking for a line plot with time on the x-axis and the value of 'column1' on the y-axis

I have managed to make something work with JSON data in a different format like this:

```
{"2017-09-20T11:14:18.000Z","values":["column1":2.1,"column2":3.0]}
```

but ideally I would like to avoid having to change the format of the JSON as it is used elsewhere. Apologies if I am missing something obvious, I thought examples of this would be easier to find!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, you probably want to pass to the line generator and scale functions an array containing either objects or arrays with both date and value, this is most in keeping with how d3.line() constructs paths.

So, while you don't need to change the structure of the json you feed the script that is charting the data, the script that charts the data will need to create something with an altered structure.

This sort of data structuring is often required in d3, and consequently there are a number of d3 helper functions to aid in this process. Considering your example dataframe, two helper functions come to mind in helping plot data in d3, `d3.keys()` and `d3.map()`:

> #### d3.keys(object) <>
>
> Returns an array containing the property names of the specified object
>   (an associative array). The order of the returned array is undefined.

And, in d3.map() we are mostly concerned about map.entries():

> #### map.entries() <>
>
> Returns an array of key-value objects for each entry in this map. The
>   order of the returned entries is arbitrary. Each entry’s key is a
>   string, but the value has arbitrary type.

Taking your json:

```
{"column1":{"2017-09-20T11:14:18.000Z":2.1,"2017-09-20T11:14:19.000Z":2.3,"2017-09-20T11:14:20.000Z":2.4}}
```

We can use (I've added a second column for demonstration):

```js
var df = {"column1":{"2017-09-20T11:14:18.000Z":2.1,"2017-09-20T11:14:19.000Z":2.3,"2017-09-20T11:14:20.000Z":2.4},
"column2":{"2017-09-20T11:14:18.000Z":2.3,"2017-09-20T11:14:19.000Z":2.1,"2017-09-20T11:14:20.000Z":2.2}};
 
var dataSeries = d3.keys(df);  // get each column
var dataArray = [];            // the data array that we will plot
 
dataSeries.forEach(function(d) {
 dataArray.push(d3.map(df[d]).entries()); // get each key value pair and return as an object
 })
 
console.log(dataArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

This outputs an array containing each series. Each series contains an object of key value pairings which we can use to plot the data. This will make graphing the data relatively straight forward, and there should be many more examples using this data structure to help too.

*Note that this approach does not require that each column have the same number of entries or the same keys (in this case, the same dates).*

A simple graph using this method might look like:

```js
var width = 500, height = 200;

////////////// structure data

var df = {"column1":{"2017-09-20T11:14:18.000Z":2.1,"2017-09-20T11:14:19.000Z":2.3,"2017-09-20T11:14:20.000Z":2.4},
"column2":{"2017-09-20T11:14:18.000Z":2.3,"2017-09-20T11:14:19.000Z":2.1,"2017-09-20T11:14:20.000Z":2.2}};
 
var dataSeries = d3.keys(df);
var dataArray = [];
 
dataSeries.forEach(function(d) {
 dataArray.push(d3.map(df[d]).entries()); // get each key value pair and return as an object
})

////////////// scale and draw data

var timeParse = d3.utcParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ");
 
var x = d3.scaleTime()
   .domain(d3.extent(dataArray[0], function(d) { return timeParse(d.key); }) )
   .range([0,width]);
   
 var y = d3.scaleLinear()
   .domain(d3.extent(dataArray[0], function(d) { return d.value; }) )
   .range([0,height])
   
 var line = d3.line()
   .x(function(d) {return x(timeParse(d.key)); })
   .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); })
   
 var svg = d3.select("body")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("width",width)
   .attr("height",height);
   
 svg.selectAll(null)
   .data(dataArray)
   .enter()
   .append("path")
   .attr("d",line)
   .attr("stroke", function(d,i) { return ["steelblue","orange"][i]; })
   .attr("stroke-width",2)
   .attr("fill","none");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

*Note I've scaled the data only according to the first column in the dataframe*

Comment: Thanks, great answer!